# Customized loss function for classification

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have a classification problem with target Y taking integer values from 1 to 20. My loss function is defined in following way:

```
def loss_func(y, y_pred):
    numData = len(y)
    diff = y-y_pred
    averageDif = np.mean(diff)
    averageAbsDif = np.mean(np.absolute(diff))
    up = sum(x > 0 for x in diff)
    down = sum(x < 0 for x in diff)
    balanceOffBy= abs(down-up)/float(numData)
    distanceFromIdeal = 0
    requiredPortion = [0.3,0.6,0.9]
    res = {}

    for num in range(-2,3):
        res['count'+str(num)] = sum(x == num for x in diff)

    count = np.cumsum([res['count0'],res['count1']+res['count-1'],res['count2']+res['count-2']])

    for prop,val in zip(requiredPortion,count):
        penalty = 0
        if val < prop*numData:
            penalty = (prop*numData-val)/(prop*numData)

        if penalty != 0:
            distanceFromIdeal += 1+penalty

    if distanceFromIdeal != 0:
        loss = 10 + distanceFromIdeal
    else:
        loss = 4*averageAbsDif+6*balanceOffBy+2*abs(averageDif)
    return score
```

In this case I not only care about the exact match, but also the distance between y and y_pred, so this may not be a standard classification problem. Can anyone provide any suggestions about which way I should go? Is it possible to use custom loss function to any of the classification libraries included in sklearn?

Comment: You should start with analysing your loss-function. Most classifiers available in scikit-learn are convex-optimization problems, so your loss (which is probably non-convex) won't work (even when changing the code of the classifiers). There is also no support in the library for this i think. There is much work to do to optimize something like this. Even, when sticking to some convex-optimization algorithm like stochastic-gradient, you would need to build a gradient of your loss first, which might not be easy. This can probably be done with *autograd*. Start learning about optimization-theory.

Comment: @sascha Thanks for the comments. I know the loss function is tricky, I thought SGD might be used, can you provide some references about the autograd method?

Comment: [autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd) is just library trying to calculate gradients of numpy code. With some changes, it might work for you (not all numpy-functions are supported yet; have a look at [this](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/blob/master/examples/logistic_regression.py) tiny LogReg example). SGD might give some results, but as you objective is probably non-convex, these are at best local-optimums. (Smoothness of your function plays also a role here). An alternative to autograd would be a much more messy implementation of your loss in *tensorflow* or *theano*.